# Normalized price process $Z(t)=\frac{\Pi(t)}{B(t)}$

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-processes, martingale, normalization

If an interest rate model with the following $P$-dynamics for the short rate.

$$dr(t)=\mu(t,r(t))dt+\sigma(t,r(t))d\bar{W}(t)$$

Now consider a $T$-claim of the form $\chi = \Phi(r(T))$ with corresponding price process $Π(t)$.

Can anyone help me to find stochastic differential of $Π(t)$ ?

and show that the normalized price process

$$Z(t)=\frac{\Pi(t)}{B(t)}$$

is a $Q$-martingale.?

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: My teacher told me that stochastic differential of $Π(t)$ is of the form $dΠ(t) = r(t)Π (t) dt + σ_Π Π(t)dW(t)$ but I don't know how to show that .

Comment: Your equation is simply the risk neutral dynamics. Do you know how to change a measure to the risk-neutral?

Comment: Hi @StudentT , Yes I know how to change a measure to the risk-neutral. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Know that $dB_t=r_tB(t)dt$ . Ito's formula give us
\begin{align}
dZ(t)=\frac{1}{B(t)}d\,\Pi(t)-\frac{\Pi(t)}{B\,^2(t)}dB(t)+0
\end{align}
As your teacher mentioned, $d\Pi(t)=r(t)\Pi(t)dt+\sigma(\Pi(t),t)dW(t)$,Thus we have
\begin{align}
& dZ(t)=\frac{1}{B(t)}[r(t)\Pi(t)dt+\sigma(\Pi(t),t)dW(t)]-\frac{\Pi(t)}{B\,^2(t)}r(t)B(t)dt\\
& dZ(t)=\frac{1}{B(t)}r(t)\Pi(t)dt+\frac{1}{B(t)}\sigma(\Pi(t),t)dW(t)-\frac{1}{B(t)}r(t)\Pi(t)dt\\
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
 dZ(t)=\frac{1}{B(t)}\sigma(\Pi(t),t)dW(t)
\end{align}
Martingale Representation Theorem shows that $Z(t)$ is a Martingale.